# Probability of a conditional in a game with biased coins

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The following is a problem in a 2022 logic textbook. I am convinced that the author's solution is incorrect and I would appreciate seeing what answer others might offer. (I will reveal the author's answer and my own answer later.)

**Smith's Coins.** Smith has 10 coins, each given to a different person, A, B, C,... Five of the coins are double-headed and five are double-tailed. Each person knew the following: If they flip and it lands heads, they win 1.00 dollar; if they flip and it lands tails, they lose 0.50 dollars; nothing happens if they don't flip. Three of the 5 people who received a double-headed coin knew their coin was double-headed, while 2 of the 5 people who received a double-tailed coin knew their coin was double-tailed; the rest thought they were flipping a fair coin. Everyone was rational, risk-neutral, and wanted to win.

Think about person A. Given what we know, we can be certain of the following:

- If A got a double-headed coin and knew it, she flipped and won.
- If A got a double-tailed coin and knew it, she didn't flip and neither won nor lost anything.
- If A thought she had a fair coin, she flipped (since she was rational and flipping maximized her expected utility given her evidence).

Question: What is the probability that "If A flipped, she won"?

More precisely, letting *W* = "A Won", *F* = "A Flipped", what is Pr(If *F* then *W*) or, equivalently, what is Pr(*F*-->*W*)?

Comment: Well, what answer do you get?  What is the official answer and what problem do you have with it?

Comment: Please see below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Person A flips the coin in 8/10 of cases, which includes the 3/10 of cases where she has a double headed coin and the 5/10 of cases where she doesn't know what coin she has. In all of the 3/10 double headed cases, she gets heads, and in 2/5 of the 5/10 unsure cases does she get heads (since two of the unmarked coins are actually double headed).

There are 8 cases where she flips the coin, and she gets heads in 5 of them. The chance that she wins given that she flips is 5/8. Put another way, all we know from the fact that she flipped is that she's a random person who *isn't* one of the ones who knows they have a double tailed coin. There are 8 such people, 5 of which have a double headed coin, and 3 of which have a double tailed coin.

Answer (score 0):

This is the author's answer:

*"Here, there is a natural intuition that this conditional's probability is equal to the probability that A received a double-headed coin, namely 1/2. After all, she either received a double-headed coin or a double-tailed coin, and if she flipped a double-headed coin, she won, whereas if she flipped a double-tailed coin, she lost."*

The author then goes on to point out that *"not everyone shares the judgment that [the answer] is 1/2."*

But I believe this "intuition" is referring to the unconditional probability that A wins, namely Pr(*W*) and does not account for the bias towards winning introduced by flipping, since, if A found herself among the 2 people who knew they had losing coins she would not flip. Since 8 people flipped (the 3 who knew they got a winning coin plus the 5 that thought they were flipping utility-maximizing fair coins), and out of those, 5 actually had winning coins, then Pr(*F*-->*W*) = 5/8.

Comment: There are $8$ people who will flip the coin...everybody but the $2$ $TT$ people who know that they have $TT$.  Of those $8$, only the five $HH$ people will win.  So the answer is $\frac 58$. Note, however, that the author doesn't appear to be claiming that the answer actually is $\frac 12$.  Instead, at least in the passage you quote, they are merely asserting that some people might intuit that the answer was $\frac 12$.  That's a much weaker claim.

Comment: Should have said:  I don't especially agree with the author that $\frac 12$ is intuitive.  The fact that more $HH$ people know what they are holding breaks the symmetry.  Of course, intuition is  subjective.

Comment: I would agree with you that, from the sentence that I quoted, it is not entirely clear where exactly the author stands. But, in the context of the chapter where this was written, the author does agree with the "natural intuition" that he refers to (namely that the answer is 1/2), and proceeds with that "natural intuition" further in the chapter, while hedging that not everyone accepts that "intuition." I would add that, "intuitions" notwithstanding, there is a correct approach and answer here, which is 5/8.

Comment: If the author claims that $\frac 12$ is the correct answer, I would set the book aside.  It clearly isn't.  This isn't any sort of fascinating paradox, it's a straightforward computation.  As a general remark:  I think intuition is just about useless in probability.  For straightforward problems, sure.  And sometimes intuition can give you an estimate.  But otherwise, set it aside in favor of direct computation.

Comment: As a side note:  the entire gambling industry (not to mention state lotteries and such) thrives precisely because probabilistic intuition is terrible.  You can even fool professionals.

Comment: The author is a tenured MIT logician, that's why I was so surprised at his appeal to what I consider to be an incorrect "intuition." The main reason for my post was to find out if there was something that I was missing or not understanding. The book has other issues which I might present in other posts to see if others agree with my own assessment. But it also has some interesting and innovative things in it, so I wouldn't discard it quite yet.

Comment: I agree that over-reliance on "intuitions," while sometimes a good starting point, is ultimately foolhardy, and should not supplant proper analysis. Indeed, probabilistic intuitions are notoriously unreliable, even for trained probabilists/statisticians--the Monty Hall problem being a notable exemplar.

Comment: To be fair, the larger context of this problem is not the probability "problem" presented above (I agree it's not much of a fascinating "paradox"), it's something a bit more subtle. Namely, whether the probability of an indicative conditional Pr("if A then C") can be modeled using the conditional probability of the corresponding Consequent given the Antecedent, Pr(C|A). It turns out that, if one makes the identification Pr(A-->C)=Pr(C|A), along with some mild logical assumptions, it results in a "trivialization" of the ensuing language. This has been plaguing logicians for the last 5 decades.